# How to put elements in specific locations in a np array in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm writing in Python 3.6, with Numpy 1.20.1. The problem is I have an `np.ndarray` called `A` with size `(10, 3)`, and I have another `np.ndarray` called `B` with size `(4, 3)`. For the 4 arrays of size 3, I would like to put them into 4 specific positions in the first array.

For example:

```
   A = np.zeros((10, 3))
   B = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
   idx = [7,3,1,4]
```

And I would like to put each row in `B` to `A`by the order in idx. So after the conversion, `A` should look like:

```
[0, 0, 0],
[7, 8, 9],
[0, 0, 0],
[4, 5, 6],
[10, 11, 12],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0 ,0],
[1, 2, 3],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0].
```

I especailly wonder if it's possible to accomplish this in one line code.

I tried `A[idx] = B`, and it gives me error: `IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: Are you sure that expression produces that error?  It doesn't for me!

Answer (score 1):

Numpy version one liner.

```
A = np.zeros((10, 3)) 
B = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]) 
idx = [7,3,1,4] 
                                                                                  
A[idx] = B[ np.arange(B.shape[0]) ]  # Source from B.shape
```

OR

```
a[idx] = B[[0,1,2,3]]   # Source as constants
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine for me.
As for the problem, you can try:

```
for i, row in zip(idx, B):
    A[i] = row
```